# configure dns in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, dns, coredns

good afternoon. I have a problem with a multi-tenant architecture that I am setting up in kubernetes. it consists of two pods (front and back), the front hits a url that points to the backend and in the back I have the different clients (tenants) that I have.
the config of the nginx of the back is defined in the following way:

```
server_name ~^(?<account>.+)\-backend.domain.com$;
  root /var/www/html/tenant/$account-backend/;
  index index.php;
```

this means that if I want to get to the backend from the frontend it would be with a url like this: tenant1.backend.domain.com

the frontend is exposed with a nodeport type service and a load balancer.
the backend is exposed locally with a ClusterIP type service which is the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
type: Service
metadata:
  name: service-clusterip-app-backend
  namespace: app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app-nginx
```

When I upload the cluster and go to the frontend and make a request, the pod can't resolve the tenant1.backend.domain.com. I've tried configuring some redirection rules through coredns, but I don't understand how it works:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:  
  name: coredns-custom  
  namespace: kube-system 
data:
  zoomcrm.server: |
    tenant1.backend.domain.com {
      forward . service-clusterip-app-backend:80
    }
```

basically what i need is for the frontend to know where to go when the url of the request is tenant1.backend.domain.com. i've looked into it but nothing i've done has worked.

Comment: Is your frontend app running on the client rather than in the cluster?

Comment: @Matt the front end is exposed with a nodeport type service that points to a balancer that has a static ip configured and from there I access the front end.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to forward the DNS request to the reuqired DNS base on the forward rule. Like this. That means you will forward the resolving request of zone tenant1.backend.domain.com(*.tenant1.backend.domain.com) to the DNS server.

```
data:
  zoomcrm.server: |
    tenant1.backend.domain.com {
      forward . <customDNSserver>:<dns port>
    }
```

Description:
The forward plugin re-uses already opened sockets to the upstreams. It supports UDP, TCP and DNS-over-TLS and uses in band health checking.

the description of forward plugin of coredns can be found [here](https://coredns.io/plugins/forward/). You can check this [post](https://alphatango086.medium.com/how-to-setup-private-dns-server-in-aks-6f080e007823) to build up your dns server in kubernetes for name resolving if you are interested.

In your case, if you only need to add single dns record for resolve inside kubernetes. You can either use hostalias in this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/), or use coredns file plugin to add zone in your coredns for name resolving, [here](https://coredns.io/plugins/file/) is the document.